# laravel when i use parameters in the function the view template get missed up

Tags: javascript, laravel-6

I'm using laravel to build a project.

there are two functions that do the same thing but one with parameters and the other I specify the values my self.
when I specify the values my self everything works well.
like this function:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $x =  Sentence::where('user_id' , '1')->get();
        return view('sentences.index')->with('x', $x);
    }
```

this works well.

but when I send parameters the view template that I extend is missed up and my javascript code in the view is not working.
like this function:

```
    public function list($column, $value)
    {
        $x =  Sentence::where($column, $value)->get();
        return view('sentences.index')->with('x', $x);
    }
```

this return the values correctly but the template is missed up.

is this because of the javascript or not??
and how to solve it??

Comment: The error here could be in column name or the value you passing. What the actual error is displayed for you ?

Comment: the columns is correct i checked myself the data returned is correct.
there is no error just that the template missed up,
no css or js just HTML .

Comment: How you displaying the variable '$x' in blade template ??

Comment: You are sending both index() and list() to the same view. Is that your intention? Your request will both create a collection. On the index() with one row. The other possibly many. That shouldn't be the cause of the view not functioning. It is not clear why index() is working and list() not on the same view. You have to use a loop, anyway. The worst that can happen is an empty result. That shouldn't be a problem either.